# How to return a String Array

Tags: java, arrays, string

My code is supposed to separate a given String and covert the chosen letters into # and separate and concatenate the words with the chosen letter. My problem is with one of the methods (allWordsWith) in my code, it won't allow me to return a String array. (p.s, the codes that run this one are irrelevant, I'm not supposed to edit those).

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class LipogramAnalyzer {
    private String line;
    public LipogramAnalyzer(String text){
         line = text;
    }
    public String mark (char letter){
        String replaceletters = line.replace(letter, '#');
        return replaceletters;
    }
    public String[] allWordsWith (char letter){
        String[] arr = line.split(" ");    
        for ( String ss : arr) {
            String ary[] = {ss};
                for(int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++){
                    int numindex = ss.indexOf(letter);
                    if (numindex != -1){
                        String result = ary[i];
                        return result;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to return a string from that method which is supposed to return a string array.

Comment: You should always provide the details of the error. "It won't allow me" is not specific.

Answer (score 2):

*"It won't allow me to return a String array"*

Sure it will. You're attempting to return a `String`:

```
String result = ary[i];
return result;
```

Even though the return type is a string array:

```
public String[] allWordsWith (char letter){
```

You need to return an array, as `allWordsWith` implies you want multiple values.

But the bigger problem is that you are initializing the result array to a single element

```
String ary[] = {ss};
```

and thes lengths of arrays can't be changed after initialization. This means that `ary.length` in this loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++){
```

will always equal one. That is not what you want.

In addition, you are searching the strings in the *result* array (`ary`), even though you just created it, meaning it ***has nothing in it***--that is, all the values are `null`.

If you want a list of all the strings in `line` that have the `letter` in it, try

```
public String[] allWordsWith (char letter){
    String[] asAllWordsInLine = line.split(" ");    
    java.util.ArrayList<String> alsAllWordsWithChar = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    for ( String ss : asAllWordsInLine) {
       if(ss.indexOf(letter) != -1)  {
          alsAllWordsWithChar.add(ss);
          continue;   //No need to check any more letters.
       }
    }
    return  alsAllWordsWithChar.toArray(new String[alsAllWordsWithChar.size()]);
}
```

I've changed the array to a list, since you can't know how many strings will have `letter` in it. A list can change size, an array can't. When no strings match, this returns an empty array, [which is preferred over `null`](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=59). ([more info](https://www.google.com/search?q=Prefer%20empty%20items%20to%20null%20ones))

I've also made the variable names more meaningful, and stopped checking a word after it matches a character (with `continue`, which short-circuits the current for-loop iteration).

Finally, the function is not returning anything until *all* strings have been analyzed, meaning after the for-loop completes. In your original code the `return` is inside the loop, meaning only the *first* string is returned.

A useful testing function:

```
public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
     testLine('b', "abc def ghi cba def ghi");
}
private static final void testLine(char c_letter, String s_line)  {  
   System.out.println("Line: \"" + s_line + "\"");  
   String[] asAllWordsWith = (new LipogramAnalyzer(s_line)).allWordsWith(c_letter);  
   System.out.println("Words with '" + c_letter + "': " + Arrays.toString(asAllWordsWith));  
}
```

Comment: This is probably the problem indeed. But shouldn't the compiler give errors if you're trying to return a String when it expects an array?

Comment: Who says it didn't? I think the "it" in "It won't allow me to..." is the compiler.

Comment: I tried changing the String result, i still get the same error.

Comment: Error message must be that the method is not returning anything.

Comment: Then there is no path of execution in the method that has accessable return statement

Comment: @SplattColor: If this answer has helped you, please consider up-voting it, and accepting it by clicking the big green check-mark. Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

Return the `ary` not `ary[i]`

```
 for(int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++){
                        int numindex = ss.indexOf(letter);
                        if (numindex != -1){
                            String result = ary[i];
                         /*here*/   return ary;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return an array. Try `return ary` instead of `return ary[i]`.

Also, your function must return something in all cases. In other words, you have to have a return statement after your for loops.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a `String` instead of `String[]` (String array) 
Change the code:

```
if (numindex != -1) {
    String result = ary[i];
    return result;
}
```

To:

```
if (numindex != -1) {
    return new String[]{ary[i]};
}
// afrer first for loop
return arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] allWordsWith (char letter){
    String[] arr = line.split(" ");    
    for ( String ss : arr) {
        String ary[] = {ss};
            for(int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++){
                int numindex = ss.indexOf(letter);
                if (numindex != -1){
                    String result = ary[i];
                    // or here return ary;
                }
            }
    }
    return ary;
}
```

Return the array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a complete String-Array at once, I have modified your function (not tested):

```
public String[] allWordsWith (char letter){
    String[] arr = line.split(" ");
    String[] result = new String[ary.length];
    for ( String ss : arr) {
        String ary[] = {ss};
            for(int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++){
                int numindex = ss.indexOf(letter);
                if (numindex != -1){
                    result[i] = ary[i];
                }
            }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you're returning a String instead of a String[]. Also note that your code will only ever return a single "word".  I modified your code to add every word that contains your character and add it to a List. At the end of the loop the List is converted to a String[].

```
public String[] allWordsWith(char letter)
{
    String[] arr = line.split(" ");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String ss : arr) {
        int numindex = ss.indexOf(letter);
        if (numindex != -1) {
            result.add(ss);
        }
    }
    return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
}
```